# How to multiply Tensors in Theano

Tags: theano, deep-learning, dot-product

I have two tensors and a weight matrix in Theano. 
Tensor A has dimension (k, 5, 40). Tensor B has dimension (k, 5, 40). Weight matrix W has dimension (40,40). I would like to compute
A*W*B. What is the correct sequence of Theano tensor operations to achieve this? Note that k can vary during run time but other dimensions are fixed.
The semantics we want from A*W*B is the following:

Think of A as a collection of k (5,40) matrices. Call them A_1, ..., A_k
Think of B as a collection of k (5,40) matrices. Call them B_1, ..., B_k.
We want to find A_{i} * W * B_{i}^{T} for all i from 1 to k. I tried using theano.tensor.dot but it seems quite confusing.

Note that a non-efficient way of doing this is to use the scan function. But this would make an inherently parallel code sequential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, but I don't know what did you mean "confusing"?

I've try using small case, I hope it can represent your case. Dot-product using `theano.tensor.dot` between three dimensional tensor and two dimensional matrix:

```
import numpy as np
import theano
import theano.tensor as T

a = T.tensor3('a', dtype='int64')
c = T.matrix('c',dtype='int64')
d = T.dot(a,c)

g = theano.function([a,c],d)

x = np.array([[[1,2],[1,3]],[[2,2],[1,1]]], dtype=int)
y = np.array([[1,2],[1,3]], dtype=int)
print g(x,y)
```

the output:

```
[[[ 3  8]
  [ 4 11]]

 [[ 4 10]
  [ 2  5]]]
```

It works like your logic, matrix `c` do dot-product only in the second and third dimension.

**UPDATE**

that first code above, you can use for the first operation in your case (A*W). Sorry I'm not calculate carefully, of course after that operation the output become three dimensional tensor. So, to perform (AW)*B you must use different approach. To perform multiplication between two three dimensional tensors I usually using scan:

```
import numpy as np
import theano
import theano.tensor as T

a = T.tensor3('a', dtype='int64')
c = T.tensor3('c',dtype='int64')
d, b = theano.scan(lambda i: T.dot(a[i,:], c[i,:]),sequences=T.arange(2))
g = theano.function([a,c],d)

x = np.array([[[1,2],[1,3]],[[2,2],[1,1]]], dtype=int)
y = np.array([[[1,2],[1,3]],[[2,2],[1,1]]], dtype=int)
print g(x,y)
```

**but** I know there are another approach using `theano.tensor.batched_dot` (`theano.tensor.dot` I think only  for 2D and 1D array). In your case it's simple to code like this:

```
e = T.batched_dot(a,c)
g = theano.function([a,c],e)
```

the code above give the same results. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Malioboro! I was able to do that as well! The problem comes with the second multiplication. The question asks for a 3-way multiplication, not two. We need to multiply A and W and then (A*W) and (B) to get (A*W*B). It is this A*W*B step which I do not get. How do we go from A*W, which you have generated in your answer to (A*W)*B. Thanks!

Comment: oh sorry @Sahil, I miscalculate the dimension, I've update my answer

Comment: Hi Malioboro, In your above example, I want to multiply 3D tensor with a matrix dot product. Like `c = T.matrix('c'), y = np.array([[1,2], [3,4]])`. It is fine with looping using scan function. But using T.batched_dot(a,c) gives correct value with error like `ValueError: get_scalar_constant_value detected deterministic IndexError: `. Could you help ?